# osmdroid xml file

Tags: android

I've made an API that uses the `osmdroid jar file` and it is fixed on the center of London. The program works fine and you can navigate on the map but I still get this error in the `main.xml` file :

`"org.osmdroid.views.MapView failed to instantiate"`

Is there something I should do? Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapview">
    </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already found the answer yourself, but you don't have to be worry about it. I also have this in my project when I use a map view from osmdroid, even with google maps and it works fine. As you can see in my screenshot:

[image]

It's not needed to add " xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" " in your org.osmdroid.views.Mapview tag. The only place where you have to add the xmlns is in your root layout item. In this case, as it it's done well, in your LinearLayout. See my code below of an example of my osmdroid tag and it's working fine:

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/osmMV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Have a nice development!

Kr